# printing multiple things with fmt.Printf in Go

Tags: go

I am just learning Go and would like to know if there is a way to merge operations like `fmt.Printf("%t \n", f1)` and `fmt.Printf("%t \n", f2)` together.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for this?

```
fmt.Printf("%t \n%t \n", f1, f2)
```